# Python bindings for OpenCV with AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FeatureDetector_create'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, surf, object-detection

I am using the python bindings for OpenCV 2.4.X and OpenCV 3.1 but with the following simple two-liner

```
import cv2
detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SURF")
```

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "version_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SURF")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FeatureDetector_create'
```

What are the reasons for this error in each version?

Comment: Your example works for me, using version 2.4.2.

Comment: I don't think you have version 2.4.3.  Your output shows the version to be `$Rev: 4557 $`, which looks like a subversion revision.  OpenCV stopped using subversion last summer, and 2.4.3 was released in the fall (see http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki).

Comment: Thanks, it seemed the I need opencv-devel and opencv-debuginfo rpm packages as well.

Comment: @pevogam Since you've found the answer to your problem, can you post it as an answer, and accept your answer so that this question can be marked as "answered"?

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059134/adding-modules-from-opencv-contrib-to-opencv

First you need intall opencv_contrib:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561910/opencv-python-cant-use-surf-sift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seemed that I need opencv-devel and opencv-debuginfo (rpm/deb) packages as well for the 2.4.X version.

Regarding the 3.1 version, these functions have been removed in favor of functions like

```
detector = cv2.TYPE_create()
```

where `TYPE` can be `ORB` or other detector of your choosing but not `SURF` and `SIFT` which have been moved to a [nonfree](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) package. For more info check this [source](http://www.aichengxu.com/other/6815650.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the following line of code:

```
detector=cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
```

You can also set Hessian Threshold.

```
detector=cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)
```

Here Hessian Threshold=400

Comment: Why does this fix the problem?  Also, please format the code so it's easily readable.