# Can't use SURF, SIFT in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, sift, surf

I'm trying a simple thing like

```
detector = cv2.SIFT()
```

and get this bad error

```
detector = cv2.SIFT()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT'
```

I do not understand that because cv2 is installed.

`cv2.__version__` is

```
$Rev: 4557 $
```

My system is Ubuntu 12.04.

Maybe someone has got the same problem and could help me.

**EDIT:**

Long story short, *testypypypy.py*:

```
import cv2

detector = cv2.SIFT()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testypypy.py", line 3, in <module>
    detector = cv2.SIFT()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT
```

If I take `SURF` it works because `SURF` is in `dir(cv2)` but if I also take `cv2.BFMatcher()` I get the same error... So it's missing and I have to add it but I don't know how.

Comment: did you look at the output of dir(cv2) to see if SIFT was listed?

Comment: there is only `'SIFT_COMMON_PARAMS_AVERAGE_ANGLE','SIFT_COMMON_PARAMS_FIRST_ANGLE'` listed. Can i update "SIFT" and more things like "cv2.BFMatcher()" ??? IF Yes, how ? :) thanks

Comment: Steps suggested by Marten worked for me. :)
I tried it on Ubuntu 12.4 running on AWS. One thing i changed in step 4: use 'sudo make install' instead of 'make install' I was also able to make SIFT & SURF work on Fedora using instructions from link below:
http://www.g7smy.co.uk/?p=366

Comment: Perhaps you have a newer version of OpenCV: try `cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create` instead of `cv2.SURF` (many tutorials are using the old call).

Comment: SIFT and SURF are in the contributed library section and must be included specifically with the install. see https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/dca/group__xfeatures2d__nonfree.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think this is far from the "correct" way to do it (the "correct" way on Ubuntu seems to be to stick to a broken and/or outdated OpenCV), but for me building opencv-2.4.6.1 from source brings back cv2.SIFT and cv2.SURF.

Steps:

1. Download opencv-2.4.6.1.tar.gz from [opencv.org](http://opencv.org).
2. Extract the source:

   ```
   tar -xf opencv-2.4.6.1.tar.gz -C /tmp
   ```
3. Configure the source. This will tell OpenCV to install into .opencv-2.4.6.1 in your home directory:

   ```
   cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
         -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
         -D WITH_XINE=ON \
         -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
         -D WITH_TBB=ON \
         -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
         -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
         -D WITH_V4L=ON \
         -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/.opencv-2.4.6.1 \
         /tmp/opencv-2.4.6.1
   ```
4. Build and install:

   ```
   cd /tmp/opencv-2.4.6.1
   make -j4
   make install
   ```
5. Set PYTHONPATH (this works in bash, I have no clue about other shells):

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=~/.opencv-2.4.6.1/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
   ```

Now if I start python and import cv2 (for me, this produces a gnome-keyring warning), I have cv2.SIFT and cv2.SURF available.

Comment: I've tried this out but got still the same Error. Is it possible to delete opencv fully and will it help?!

Comment: Is it the new or old cv2 that is loaded? What does `print cv2.__version__` say?

Comment: print cv2.__version__ says $Rev: 4557 $

Comment: @Linda: Then it loads the old one. Restart python, and try `import os,sys`, followed by `os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/.opencv-2.4.6/lib'))` and `sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/.opencv-2.4.6.1/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'))`, and then check which version it loads. It should be the new one.

Comment: well its working now!!! Thank you (but its still $Rev: 4557 $
!!! And do i  always have to put this lines into my code? Is there a possible way to fix it for ever ? BTW: its `os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/.opencv-2.4.6.1/lib'))`

Comment: @Linda: All I have to do is to set PYTHONPATH before i start python (i do this in my .bashrc, so it is done on login), and then I can import cv2. I dont have the old and broken opencv though, and it feels like your system is confused as to which to load. If you have sudo rights you could try removing it (you can always reinstall it if you want it back); as far as I understand, the command `sudo apt-get remove libopencv-* libcv-*` should be enough for this.

Comment: You can do pretty much this same process with openCV 3.4.3 (I did 3.4.3.18), but you need to have the opencv-contrib source as well. Add the following flags to the cmake command: `-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NON_FREE=ON` and `-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/path/to/opencv_contrib-3.4.3/modules`. This is what I had when building it on raspbian 4.14.70-v7+ (note I have examples installed too):

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.4.3/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON ..`

Answer (score 84):

There is a pip source that makes this very easy.

1. If you have another version of opencv-python installed use this command to remove it to avoid conflicts:

   ```
   pip uninstall opencv-python
   ```
2. Then install the contrib version with this:

   ```
   pip install opencv-contrib-python
   ```
3. SIFT usage:

   ```
   import cv2
   sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
   ```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Don't know why this is not upvoted.

Comment: When I do that, I get:
error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\sift.cpp:1207: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create'.
I guess the downloaded version is not compiled with OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE

Comment: As of April 2019, the latest version (v4.0.0.21) complains (@whiteShadow pointed out). You can install an older version `pip install -U opencv-contrib-python==3.4.0.12` to avoid this.

Comment: As of Sep 2019, @Falcon's suggestion worked for me. Basically uninstall `opencv-python` and install the version `3.4.2.16` of `opencv-contrib-phython`

Comment: As of February 2020 this does not work. Lowest possible version is 3.4.8.29, and the same error mentioned by @whiteShadow is thrown.

Comment: I heard that patent for SIFT patent will expire this month or next month, maybe it will come back in OpenCV.

Comment: @Apollo found any solution?

Comment: @AliİhsanElmas Yep, there's basically no other way than manually building everything. Check my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561910/cant-use-surf-sift-in-opencv/60491674#60491674

Answer (score 63):

For recent information on this issue (as of Sept 2015) consult [this page](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/).

Most information on this question here is obsolete.

What pyimagesearch is saying is that SURF/SIFT  were moved to `opencv_contrib` because of patent issues.

For installation there is also a [nice page](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) that tells you how to install opencv with `opencv_contrib` and Python support so you get SURF/SIFT.

Notice that the API also changed. Now it's like this:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

Before I found the above pages, I also suffered quite a bit. But the pages listed do a very good job of helping with installation and explaining what's wrong.

Comment: cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() <-- thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: what about `cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SIFT")`? What will be its substitute?

Comment: @lysdexia How did you get ` 
cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` working? It is still giving me `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
`. How did you install opencv and opencv_contriv? I did `pip install python-opencv` and next steps from the page linked in the OP.

Comment: This seems a rather lengthy process, on the other hand doing `pip install python-opencv` and `pip install opencv-contrib-python
` solves the issues immediately.

Comment: I too don't see `xfeatures2d` as available in the current version of OpenCV

Comment: I installed an config referring this https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/ 
and change to this cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() do the trick :D

Answer (score 30):

FYI, as of 3.0.0 SIFT and friends are in a contrib repo located at https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib and are not included with opencv by default.

Answer (score 9):

for debian users its 'easy' to create their own libopencv-nonfree package.

i followed the opencv tutorial for python, but in my debian the SIFT and SURF modules were missing. And there is no non-free package available for debian including SIFT and SURF etc.

They were stripped from the package due to license issues....

i never created a package for debian before (adding a new module etc) but i followed some small steps in the debian tutorials and tried and guessed around a bit, and after 1 day, voila... i got working a libopencv-nonfree2.4 deb package and a python module with correct bindings.

(i dont know if i also needed to install the newly built python-opencv package or only the nonfree... i re-installed both and got a working python opencv library with all necessary nonfree modules!)

ok, here it is:

!this is for libopencv 2.4!

!you can do all steps except installing as a normal user!

we need the built essesntials and some tools from debian repository to compile and create a new package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts
```

create a directory in your home and change to that directory:

```
cd ~ && mkdir opencv-debian
cd opencv-debian
```

download the needed packages:

```
apt-get source libopencv-core2.4
```

and download all needed dependency packages to build the new opencv

```
apt-get build-dep libopencv-core2.4
```

this will download the neeeded sources and create a directory called "opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg"

change to that directory:

```
cd opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg
```

now you can test if the package will built without modifications by typing:

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

this will take a long time!
this step should finish without errors
you now have a lot of .deb packages in your opencv-debian directory

now we make some modifications to the package definition to let debian buld the nonfree modules and package!

change to the opencv-debian directory and download the correct opencv source.. in my case opencv 2.4.9 or so

i got mine from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/releases

```
wget https://codeload.github.com/Itseez/opencv/tar.gz/2.4.9
```

this will download opencv-2.4.9.tar.gz

extract the archive:

```
tar -xzvf opencv-2.4.9.tar.gz
```

this will unpack the original source to a directory called opencv-2.4.9

now copy the nonfree modules from original source to the debian source:

```
cp -rv opencv-2.4.9/modules/nonfree opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/
```

ok, now we have the source of the nonfree modules, but thats not enough for debian... we need to modify 1 file and create a new one

we have to edit the debian control file and add a new section at end of file:
(i use mcedit as an editor here)

```
mcedit opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/debian/control
```

or use any other editor of your choice

and add this section:

```
Package: libopencv-nonfree2.4
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: OpenCV Nonfree Modules like SIFT and SURF
 This package contains nonfree modules for the OpenCV (Open Computer Vision)
 library.
 .
 The Open Computer Vision Library is a collection of algorithms and sample
 code for various computer vision problems. The library is compatible with
 IPL (Intel's Image Processing Library) and, if available, can use IPP
 (Intel's Integrated Performance Primitives) for better performance.
 .
 OpenCV provides low level portable data types and operators, and a set
 of high level functionalities for video acquisition, image processing and
 analysis, structural analysis, motion analysis and object tracking, object
 recognition, camera calibration and 3D reconstruction.
```

now we create a new file called libopencv-nonfree2.4.install

```
touch opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/debian/libopencv-nonfree2.4.install
```

and edit:

```
mcedit opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/debian/libopencv-nonfree2.4.install
```

and add the following content:

```
usr/lib/*/libopencv_nonfree.so.*
```

ok, thats it, now create the packages again:

```
cd opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg
```

first a clean up:

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
```

and build:

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

et voila... after a while you have a fresh built and a new package libopencv-nonfree2.4.deb!

now install as root:

```
dpkg -i libopencv-nonfree2.4.deb
dpkg -i python-opencv.deb
```

and test!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv2.SIFT()
kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,16,0.05,10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for i in corners:
    x,y = i.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),90,255,3)

plt.imshow(img),plt.show()
```

have fun!

Comment: This worked for me as well on Ubuntu 14.04. I can now use cv2.sift in Python.

Answer (score 6):

IN opencv3.x SIFT() & SURF() are no longer exist .for this

uninstall all the opencv versions

```
python -m pip uninstall opencv-python

python -m pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

after that install opencv-contrib to include sift() and surf() using below given command with python(3.x)

```
python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
```

then you can use

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  This is a huge contribution

Comment: This.  This is all it takes at least on Windows.

Comment: It worked for me just needed to modify it for python3 in RPI 4. But not working in windows. In windows it's saying that version not found:  

"python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16"

Answer (score 5):

As an Anaconda user, I wanted to find one or two appropriate commands to solve the problem. Fortunately, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305578/sift-cv2-xfeatures2d-sift-create-not-working-even-though-have-contrib-instal) helped. For conda 4.5.11 (use `conda -V` to check Anaconda version) I have performed next steps:

```
# Python version does not matter, most likely, check yourself
conda create -n myenv python=3.6     
conda activate myenv
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

That will install OpenCV 2.4.11. Anaconda's another [command](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3) `conda install -c menpo opencv3` will install OpenCV3, but Python has to be downgraded to 2.7. To install OpenCV3 with Python3 use next (due to the first link):

```
conda create -n myenv python  
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
```

Check the SIFT:

```
conda activate myenv
python
>>> cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
<xfeatures2d_SIFT 000002A3478655B0>
```

Comment: I have just settled on the Ubuntu and checked installation steps above with pip3 instead of pip. All works great for version 3.4.2.16. Version 4.0.0.21 restricts using SIFT and requires compilation from the source for using SIFT.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me in September 2020:

1. Remove previous versions:

   ```
   pip uninstall opencv-python
   pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
   ```
2. Install this particular version (3.4.2.16 was no longer available)

   ```
   pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17
   pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
   ```
3. Create the detectors with:

   ```
   import cv2
   sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
   surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
   ```

Answer (score 3):

just change `SHIFT` to `ORB`,
I think it make occur because of non-relevant version,
**ORB** is efficient and better alternative of **SHIFT** or **SURF**.

As I also face same problem when i was used cv2.SHIFT()

> ERROR: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT'

Now its completely working for me please try this:

`ORB = cv2.ORB()`

Answer (score 2):

since I had already compiled opencv when I discovered this problem, all I had to do was (from my opencv build directory):

```
make opencv_nonfree
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 2):

Install Python opencv

```
pip install opencv-python
```

and instead of using ..

> cv2.SIFT()

Use

> cv2.SIFT_create()

working code using **opencv-python** below

```
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread('yourimg.png',0)
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None) #keypoint and descriptors
...
```

you can also install "opencv-contrib-python" and use "cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()" but that is secondary and up to you..
working code using the python package **opencv-contrib-python**

```
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread('yourimg.png',0)
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None) #keypoint and descriptors
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this installation operation](http://jayrambhia.com/blog/install-opencv-2-4-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
    -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON 
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON 
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
```

using this command will install library to your /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Please note that not everyone has write access outside their home directory (this is especially true on campus computers). Installing at /usr/local/lib typically would require sudo rights.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install OpenCV-Contrib
2. `import cv2 
   sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()`
3. `sift.something()`

This is the easy way to install the Contrib.

Comment: It would be nice to provide some explanation to accompany your code, particularly point 2. Also note your formatting is a little off on number 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the version of opencv to 3.4.2.16 .Since it is patented it is not available in newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed in this way. It must work for you as well!

**Step 1:**

```
virtualenv venv 
source venv/bin/activate
```

---

**Step 2:**

```
sudo python3 -m pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16 
sudo python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
```

---

**Step 3:**

```
import cv2
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

---

Don't use cv2.SIFT() . It will raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

It is now back to normal opencv, thanks to the expiration of the patent!
Check this:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html
As long as your opencv version is 4.4.0+!

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by vizzy also works with OpenCV 2.4.8, as when building the non-free package under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

This dependency issue may prevent installation of the non-free package:

```
 libopencv-nonfree2.4 depends on libopencv-ocl2.4; however:
  Package libopencv-ocl2.4 is not installed.
```

Easily fixable because the missing package can be installed from the ones just built:

```
dpkg -i libopencv-ocl2.4_2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

After that the install proceeds as explained in vizzy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above suggested solutions worked for me. I use Anaconda and found that opencv version 3.3.1 still had Sift enabled.  If you want to test in isolated conda environment, try the following inspired from @A.Ametov's answer above

```
conda create -n testenv opencv=3.3.1     
conda activate testenv

conda activate myenv
python
#Check version of opencv being used
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
#Check if Sift is available
>>> cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
<xfeatures2d_SIFT 000002A3478655B0>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change this**:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

**By this**:

```
cv2.ORB_create()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following page provides a relatively good guide that requires few corrections : https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/

On step 8, when you are choosing generator for the project (tool used for building), don't forget to specify x64 in the second field if you need it. If you don't, you will get LNK1112 error, which is a linker error caused if one module is created with the x64 compiler, and another module is created with the x86 compiler.

Next, when choosing flags in step 9, don't forget to tick the "OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE", and set the path for flag "OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH" flag. The path must be set to "modules" folder in opencv-contrib-python.

So you need both opencv, and opencv-contrib-python in order to use SIFT and SURF.

Answer (score 0):

As per June 2020, I suppose this version (`pip install -U opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16`) is still working. so install it and enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

try this

!pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.44
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()