# OpenCV 'SIFT' Attribute Error

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I wrote this function for comparison of keypoints of frames of a video.

```
def match_images(img1, img2):
    """Given two images, returns the matches"""
       detector = cv2.SIFT(100)
       matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2)

       kp1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
       kp2, desc2 = detector.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

       raw_matches = matcher.knnMatch(desc1, trainDescriptors = desc2, k = 2) 
       kp_pairs = filter_matches(kp1, kp2, raw_matches)
       return kp_pairs
```

And I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 173, in <module>
    kp_pairs = match_images(img1, img2)
  File "test.py", line 18, in match_images
    detector = cv2.SIFT(100)
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT'
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback exception?

Comment: Which version of opencv do you have?

Comment: are you on windows/linux ?

Comment: @MihaiZamfir:am using linux debian

Comment: OK, in this case have you tried the steps provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561910/opencv-python-cant-use-surf-sift

Comment: @MihaiZamfir:i have done those steps.but it ain't working.same error is repeating.pls do some help.

Comment: can you see which openCV version do you have? are you sure you have instsalled the correct one?

Comment: it lokks like openCV-2.4.8 on the downloaded directory.

Comment: well, make sure it is installed as well, not just downloaded. otherwise, I don;t know why it is not working...

Comment: @IritMalka,@Mihai Zamfir: i have newly installed openCV 2.3.1-11

Comment: well, then you haven't installed the newest one. you have an old version installed. please follow the steps in the link I provided to you. You need to have the new version (opencv-2.4.6.1 or later) of openCV which supports SIFT for python.

Answer (score 0):

So now that you have installed OpenCV 3 with the opencv_contrib  package, you should have access to the original SIFT and SURF implementations from OpenCV 2.4.X, only this time they’ll be in the xfeatures2d  sub-module through the cv2.SIFT_create  and cv2.SURF_create  functions.

```
python3
>>> import cv2
>>> image = cv2.imread("test_image.jpg")
>>> gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>>> sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
>>> ...
```