# Whenever I download and install any opencv version, I get the same 3.2 version

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and needed to install opencv 2.4 (to use the patented features that are not available in newer versions e.g SIFT, SURF). But whenever I install any version whether it's 2.4, 3.2 or even 3.4 and check for the version using python `cv2.__version__` it outputs `'3.2.0'`
 and hence, can't use the patented functions.

So, is there a way of using the installed version 2.4 instead of 3.2, or do I need to uninstall and reinstall?
I installed it by following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18590112

**EDIT**

I didn't uninstall the previous version properly.
The correct way to uninstall is

```
$ cd ~/opencv/build
$ sudo make uninstall
```

then delete the opencv folder

Comment: the minor version number is the "2" in 3.2, not the one in 2.4

Comment: Okay, excuse me for that. I'll edit the question

Comment: also in 4.3.0 SIFT detector has been excluded from non-free algorithms set

Comment: But the problem lies in the fact that i always get the 3.2 version, no matter which version I download from the opencv website.
Btw, I use the answer in this link https://answers.opencv.org/question/209088/how-to-completely-remove-opencv3/ to uninstall any version to try and reinstall another version.