# Emgu 4.3 Surf and Cuda Surf missing

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am upgrading a project with Emgu from 3.3 to 4.3. I've noticed that Emgu World no longer exists. Is there still a way to use Surf and Cuda Surf, or does it need to be called from OpenCV 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Surf is a patented algorithm and as such is not included in the main opencv repo, which in turn is not included in Emgucv. Surf only exists in the contrib version of opencv, which is not included in Emgucv.

For more info you can follow this [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561910/cant-use-surf-sift-in-opencv) post.

Answer (score 0):

Check this github [issue](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/325) to get more information about missing SURF. When you use commerial EmguCV version you can ask them to compile an extra version for you. But from version 4.0 on patent burdened algorithms are completely removed by default in the open source edition.